# Array of Array to table format

Tags: python, arrays

I have a array of arrays where each internal array is a variable size, and will change with each run.  e.g.:

```
a = [[T1], [4, 5, 6], ['a', 'b']]
```

What I'd like to do is print this as a table, with the 1st array as col_1, 2nd col_2, and then col_3.  Currently, there will only be 3 cols.  Desired result:

```
COL1     COL2     COL3
----     ----     ----
T1       4        a
         5        b
         6
```

I guess I have two major questions:
1. Can this be done
2. How to account for the diff sizes of each array - not in terms of formatting, but looping through elements where there might not be one.

Thanks very much.

*p.s. I'm currently experimenting with zip() as that looks like it could work, but still have a mis-matched number of elements in each array.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track with `zip`.  To fill in something where there's nothing, use `itertools.zip_longest` (in python 2, `izip_longest`):

```
for line in zip_longest(*a,fillvalue=''):
    print('\t'.join(map(str,line)))

T1      4       a
        5       b
        6
```

Answer (score 2):

> I'm currently experimenting with zip() as that looks like it could work, but still have a mis-matched number of elements in each array.

Yes, as the docs say, `zip` stops as soon as any of the arrays stops.

But the `itertools` module has a function called [`zip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) (or `izip_longest`, in 2.x) that solves this problem.

You just need specify what you want as the fill value—in this case, probably `''`:

```
for row in itertools.zip_longest(*a, fillvalue=''):
    print('\t'.join(row))
```